# US Green card holder Pakistan passport 24 hour transit Guangzhou

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, us-permanent-residents, guangzhou

I have a US green card and a Pakistani passport. I have a long layover in Guangzhou (12 hours) however as per the 24 hours TWOV policy, my passport is listed as possibly having exceptions. https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm

Does anyone know if I will be allowed the 24hour transit visa at the airport, or is there something I can apply for prior to the flight to ensure I can leave the airport?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pakistani passport holders can transit through China for a layover up to 24 hours, and you are even allowed to get an entry permit on arrival and exit the airport. There are some exceptions, though, but it appears that they do not apply to you.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, has the complete rules:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers
>   with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within
>   24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the
>   airport and have documents required for the next destination. (SEE
>   NOTE 88975)
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC),    Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX), Urumqi    (URC) and Yanji
>     (YNJ).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of Pakistan    transiting through Xiamen (XMN).
>
>   NOTE 88975: This TWOV facility does not apply when    passengers
>     arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or    Northern Mariana Isl.
>     AND depart on a direct flight to USA,    Guam or Northern Mariana Isl.
>     (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward air,
>   cruise or train ticket to a third country within 24 hours can obtain
>   an entry permit on arrival. They must have documents required for the
>   next destination.
>
> When passengers have obtained an entry permit, they can have multiple
>   transit stops within China (People's Rep.).(SEE NOTE 88975)
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Shenzhen (SZX) when    passengers are traveling to Hong Kong (SAR China) or Macao    (SAR
>     China).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC),    Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Urumqi (URC) and Yanji    (YNJ).
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of Pakistan    transiting through Xiamen (XMN).
>
>   NOTE 88975: This TWOV facility does not apply when    passengers
>     arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or    Northern Mariana Isl.
>     AND depart on a direct flight to USA,    Guam or Northern Mariana Isl.
>     (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).
>
> Warning:
>
> - All transiting passengers are subject to a check by   immigration. Passengers in transit must hold passports or   other documents
>     accepted to enter China (People's Rep.).